# Vim InsertLeave event doesn't occur when using CTRL-C instead of ESC

Tags: vim

I'm reading through Steve Losh's [Learn Vimscript the Hard Way](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/) and have added to my .vimrc

```
" make status line red while in insert mode
augroup hi_statusline
  autocmd!
  autocmd InsertEnter * hi StatusLine ctermbg=15  ctermfg=9
  autocmd InsertLeave * hi StatusLine ctermbg=238 ctermfg=253
augroup END
```

I've noticed an odd behaviour, however.  Sometimes I hit <kbd>C-c</kbd> to get out of insert mode, which works fine and is documented.  When I do this, the InsertLeave event doesn't fire.  When I use <kbd>ESC</kbd> it works fine.  Is this a known oddity of vim?  Is there perhaps a workaround, by hooking into another event that suggests InsertMode is no longer active?

EDIT | Meh, adding a `inoremap <C-c> <ESC>` resolves it and as far as I can tell has absolutely no side-effects, since C-c already does what ESC does (goes back to normal mode).  Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: +1 for "Learn Vimscript the Hard Way) reference, seems very useful!

Comment: <C-c> really means: abort all running operations. This includes scripts, and autocommands are scripts. Simple as that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
:ino <C-C> <Esc>
```

^C is conventionally the get-me-out-of-here-now-please key, if you've got an autocmd you need to not run C-C becomes your friend.

Comment: Thanks, also figured this out just before you posted too ;)  Will accept your answer once the 5 minute timeout passes and SO lets me do it ;)  I had C-c mapped to ESC in my vimrc previously, but had removed it since it I realised it already supported the behaviour... obviously with this subtlety though.

Comment: np, accept+upvote actually feels like overkill for this.  Glad it's workin for ya :-)

Answer (score 3):

This is documented under `:help i_CTRL-C`:

```
CTRL-C  Quit insert mode, go back to Normal mode.  Do not check for
        abbreviations.  Does not trigger the |InsertLeave| autocommand
        event.
```

As usual, Bram lives up to the design goals.

```
:help design-documented
```

Comment: It's also documented under `:help InsertLeave`.  But one might be forgiven for thinking that the event `InsertLeave` triggers when you leave insert mode.  Documentation is good, but intuitive design is even better.